# как протестировать заполенность модели?

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine

помогите пожалуйста написать тест для backbone/jasmine

есть модель:

```
window.APP = window.APP || {};

APP.CalcModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    errDepartCity: [],
    errDestinCity: [],
    errShippOptionsWeight: [],
    errShippOptionsVolume: []   
  }
});
```

в этой модели есть метод, который очищает свойства. пока для упрощения задачи я хотел бы инициализировать модель данными и проверить пустые поля или нет. вот мой тест:

```
describe("fill model check", function() {

  it("should errDepartCity is not empty after init", function() {
    var model = new APP.CalcModel({
      errDepartCity: ['qwerty', 'asdfgh'],
      errDestinCity: ['qwerty', 'asdfgh'],
      errShippOptionsWeight: ['qwerty', 'asdfgh'],
      errShippOptionsVolume: ['qwerty', 'asdfgh']
    });

    // console.log(model);

    expect(model.get('errDepartCity').length).toEqual(0);
  });

});
```

проблема в том, что он проходит успешно. хотя не должен потому что длина массива не нулевая. я не понимаю почему

использование `not.toEqual` вместо `.toEqual` ничего не меняет - тест проходит успешно

Comment: Есть ли другие тесты, где вы создаете `APP.CalcModel`? Если да, то проблема действительно в ссылочных типах в `defaults` как и говорит @AriesUa

Comment: Кстати, в отрыве от jasmine все работает как и должно: https://jsfiddle.net/yyq0y1z9/

Comment: Прошу прощения, ввел в заблуждение.

Comment: Но проблема передачи по ссылке существует. Вот небольшой пример, который это показывает. https://jsfiddle.net/zhf8zzu6/1/

Comment: @AriesUa, вот поэтому я и уточнил о существовании других тестов. =)